# How to encode following URL correctly

Tags: java, url, encoding

I have an URL's which I like to parse by a java app.
These urls can have characters, which can't be called by :

```
url.openStream()
```

example:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=langlinks&titles=2019–20_coronavirus_pandemic&redirects=&lllimit=400
```

there is a character – in it (2019–20_coronavirus_pandemic), which I have to encode. Resp. I would like to encode the complete URL, because it could have other special characters.

I am doing this as follow, which doesn't work for me:

```
String urlEncoded = URLEncoder.encode(wikiID, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
String sURL = "https://en.wikipedia.org" + "/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=langlinks&titles=" + urlEncoded + "&redirects=&lllimit=400";
    URL url = new URL(sURL);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

URLEncoder.encode encodes 2019–20 to 2019%3F20, which is not correct, resp. can't be called.
correct encoding would be : 2019%E2%80%9320

Howto encode the url by code correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `wikiID` has already become  corrupted by the time the code above runs.  The problem is therefore in code that you haven't shown us.

To prove this, here's a quick session in jshell.  I'm on Windows so I'm using the Unicode character escape `\u2013` for the en-dash character:

```
jshell> import java.net.URLEncoder;

jshell> import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

jshell> URLEncoder.encode("2019\u20132020_coronavirus_pandemic", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
$3 ==> "2019%E2%80%932020_coronavirus_pandemic"

jshell> URLEncoder.encode("2019?2020_coronavirus_pandemic", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
$4 ==> "2019%3F2020_coronavirus_pandemic"
```